# Tablelayout with massive data android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

What is the best way to create a **table layout** or recyclerview/listview/gridview  in android that can pull a lot of data around 1000 rows and around 50 columns each row without to crash ?

I want to show it like excel sheet nothing special just show data of course with scrolling both ways.

Comment: Why you are not preferring a listview/recyclerview?

Comment: Might be good to show only a limited number of rows at once.

Comment: couldn't figure how to do it with recyclerview/listview

Comment: Sounds like it's worth figuring out how to do it that way!

Answer (score 6):

[TableFixHeaders](https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders) project on github has an implementation with both `Adapter` an `Recycling` of views, plus handles scrolling wery nicely. And is quite easy to modify to suit your needs.

[image]

This is not so uncommon request, so it has been done numerous times. I am sure you can find other implementations if this one is not right for you.

Answer (score 3):

I saw a similar question on SO a few months ago, and I was interested to see if I could develop a solution.

My concept was to start with a `ListView` for vertical scrolling and view recycling.  Each list item is a `HorizontalScrollView` to show a table row with many columns.  The trick here is to listen to each `HorizontalScrollView` for swipe events and then scroll *every* `HorizontalScrollView` in sync with the view being swiped.

I have a proof-of-concept project on Github here:
 [klarson2/android-table-test](https://github.com/klarson2/android-table-test)

Downsides: The project was set up for Eclipse, so you can't open it directly with Android Studio.  There is still a small bug with event handling that I haven't got around to fixing.  Another limitation is that each cell view in the horizontal `LinearLayout` must be a fixed size so that the columns will line up correctly.

However, the example uses a 4MB .csv file with 50 columns and over 10,000 rows for a data source proving that it is possible to display an enormous table in an Android app with responsive two-way scrolling.